Any documentation from Microsoft regarding all possible values of WorkflowVersion
One of the task in my SharePoint 2010 style workflow is showing status "In Progress". Even after completing task, it remains at this status and doesn't move to next stage. When I check WorkflowVersion then it is showing value 1536.
Is there documentation available from Microsoft showing all possible values of this field and what they mean?
This is the field I am talking about but there is no detail about it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms448459(v=office.14)
